# Calling methods and passing proper context in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

This is the simplified version of `class` I have:

```
class Calculations
  constructor: (amount = 1000) ->
    @amount = amount

  rowOne: =>
    columnOne:   => @amount * 0.1
    columnTwo:   => @amount * 0.2
    columnThree: => @amount * 0.3
    total:       => @_total(context)

  _total: (context) ->
    context.columnOne() + context.columnTwo() + context.columnThree()
```

I want to call methods like this:

```
calc = new Calculations()

calc.rowOne().columnOne()    # And it should return 100
calc.rowOne().columnTwo()    # And it should return 200
calc.rowOne().columnThree()  # And it should return 300
calc.rowOne().total()        # And it should return 600
```

How can I implement this properly? Current implementation of `_total` method, of course, does not work, because I have no idea how can I pass needed context there. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Calculations
  constructor: (amount = 1000) ->
    @amount = amount

  rowOne: =>
    columnOne:   => @amount * 0.1
    columnTwo:   => @amount * 0.2
    columnThree: => @amount * 0.3
    total:       @_total

  _total: () ->
    this.columnOne() + this.columnTwo() + this.columnThree()
```